# Start and end of the string with comma in ios

Tags: ios, nsstring

I need to check whether the start and end of the string contains any commas(,) and remove that commas (or) replace those comma with empty string.

For Example,

```
NSString *str1 = @",a,b,c,d,"; or

NSString *str1 = @",a,b,c,d"; or

NSString *str1 = @"a,b,c,d,";
```

Output :

```
NSString *str1 = @"a,b,c,d";
```

I tried this

```
NSRange lastComma = [str1 rangeOfString:@"," options:NSBackwardsSearch];

        if(lastComma.location != NSNotFound) {
            str1 = [str1 stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:lastComma
                                                     withString: @""];
        }
```

and get the last comma deleted, but how to delete the first comma?.

Is there any way to do this, helpers are appreciated.

Comment: `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:`

Comment: You could use a NSRegularExpression, or check with `hasPrefix` or `hasSuffix` and delete the comma if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `[NSString componentsSeparatedByString:]` and then reject any empty strings.  This would have the effect of removing empty elements *within* the list as well:

```
NSArray *elements = [inputString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
NSMutableArray *outputElements = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSString *element in elements)
    if ([element length] > 0)
        [outputElements addObject:element];
```

and then reformat the string:

```
NSString *outputString = [outputElements componentsJoinedByString:@","]
```

Comment: but i need to remove the commas in start and end positions.. You said for removing empty strings,..

Answer (score 1):

You can use `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:` method of `NSSTring`.

```
NSString *str1 = @",a,b,c,d,";
NSString *str2 = @",a,b,c,d";
NSString *str3 = @"a,b,c,d,";

NSCharacterSet * punctuationCharacterSet = [NSCharacterSet punctuationCharacterSet];

NSLog(@"%@", [str1 stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:punctuationCharacterSet]);
NSLog(@"%@", [str2 stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:punctuationCharacterSet]);
NSLog(@"%@", [str3 stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:punctuationCharacterSet]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the comma from first and last of string if it has.

```
  NSString *str1 = @",a,b,c,d,";

    NSLog(@"%@",[str1 substringFromIndex:str1.length - 1]);

    if ([[str1 substringToIndex:1] isEqualToString:@","])
    {

        str1 = [str1 substringFromIndex:1];

        NSLog(@" == %@",str1);

    }
    if([[str1 substringFromIndex:str1.length - 1] isEqualToString:@","])
    {
        str1 = [str1 substringToIndex:str1.length - 1];

        NSLog(@"%@",[str1 substringToIndex:str1.length - 1]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use string manipulators functions .
1.find_last_of
2.find_first_of()

Comment: Who said anything about C++?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:` method to replace ',' with ''.

refer below code,

```
    int strLength = [str1 length];
    str1 = [str1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@"" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSRangeFromString(@"0,1")];
    str1 = [str1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@"" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSRangeFromString([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d,%d",strLength - 1,1])];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString*delete=@"a,b,c,d,";
    if ([delete hasPrefix:@","] && [delete hasSuffix:@","]) 
         delete=[ [delete substringFromIndex:1] substringToIndex:delete.length-2];
    else if ([delete hasPrefix:@","])
        delete= [delete substringFromIndex:1];
    else
        delete=[delete substringToIndex:delete.length-1];
    NSLog(@"delete---%@",delete);
```